# Prob. 10, Sec. 3.4, in Bartle & Sherbert's INTRO TO REAL ANALYSIS, 4th ed: Let $\left( x_n \right)$ be a bounded sequence of real numbers . . .

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

Here is Prob. 10, Sec. 3.4, in the book *Introduction to Real Analysis* by Robert G. Bartle & Donald R. Sherbert, 4th edition:

> Let $\left( x_n \right)$ be a bounded sequence and for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ let $s_n \colon= \sup \left\{ \ x_k \ \colon \ k \geq n \ \right\}$ and $S \colon= \inf \left\{ s_n \right\}$. Show that there exists a subsequence of $\left( x_n \right)$ that converges to $S$.

My Attempt:

> As $S = \inf \left\{ \ s_n \ \colon \ n \in \mathbb{N} \ \right\}$ and as $S+1 > S$, so $S+1$ is not a lower bound for the set $\left\{ \ s_n \ \colon \ n \in \mathbb{N} \ \right\}$, and thus there is a natural number $n_1$ such that 
>   $$ S \leq s_{n_1} < S+1. \tag{1} $$
>
> Now as $ s_{n_1} = \sup \left\{ \ x_k \ \colon \ k \in \mathbb{N}, k \geq n_1 \ \right\}$ and as $s_{n_1} - 1 < s_{n_1}$, so $s_{n_1} - 1$ is not an upper bound for the set $\left\{ \ x_k \ \colon \ k \in \mathbb{N}, k \geq n_1 \ \right\}$, and thus we can find a natural number $k_1 \geq n_1$ such that 
>   $$ s_{n_1} - 1 < x_{k_1} \leq s_{n_1}. \tag{2} $$
>
> From (1) and (2) we obtain 
>   $$ S - 1 \leq s_{n_1} - 1 < x_{k_1} \leq s_{n_1} < S+1, $$
>   and hence 
>   $$ S-1 < x_{k_1} < S + 1. \tag{3} $$
>
> Again as $S = \inf \left\{ \ s_n \ \colon \ n \in \mathbb{N} \ \right\}$ and as $S+1/2 > S$, so $S+1/2$ is not a lower bound for the set $\left\{ \ s_n \ \colon \ n \in \mathbb{N} \ \right\}$, and thus there is a natural number $n_2$ such that 
>   $$ S \leq s_{n_2} < S+\frac{1}{2}. \tag{4} $$

Can we show whether $n_2 > n_1$? Or, is this condition really needed for our proof to go through?

> Now as $s_{n_2} = \sup \left\{ \ x_k \ \colon \ k \in \mathbb{N}, k \geq n_2 \ \right\}$ and as $s_{n_2} - 1/2 < s_{n_2}$, so $s_{n_2} - 1/2$ is not an upper bound for the set $\left\{ \ x_k \ \colon \ k \in \mathbb{N}, k \geq n_2 \ \right\}$, and thus we can find a natural number $k_2 \geq n_2$ such that 
>   $$ s_{n_2} - \frac{1}{2} < x_{k_2} \leq s_{n_2}. \tag{5} $$

Can we show if $k_2 > k_1$? This condition is essential, isn't it?

> From (4) and (5) we obtain 
>   $$ S - \frac{1}{2} \leq s_{n_2} - 1 < x_{k_2} \leq s_{n_2} < S+ \frac{1}{2}, $$
>   and hence 
>   $$ S - \frac{1}{2} < x_{k_2} < S + \frac{1}{2}. \tag{6} $$

Once we have shown that our $k_2$ is indeed greater than our $k_1$, we can repeat the above process and thus obtain a subsequence $\left( x_{k_m} \right)_{m \in \mathbb{N}}$ of $\left( x_n \right)$ such that 
$$ S - \frac{1}{m} < x_{k_m} < S +  \frac{1}{m} \ \mbox{ for all } m \in \mathbb{N}.  $$
And then our desired conclusion will follow. But how to accomplish this?

P.S.:

After reading through the answer below, I think I have the idea of how to proceed.

Here is my amended proof.

> As $S = \inf \left\{ \ s_n \ \colon \ n \in \mathbb{N} \ \right\}$ and as $S+1 > S$, so $S+1$ is not a lower bound for the set $\left\{ \ s_n \ \colon \ n \in \mathbb{N} \ \right\}$, and thus there is a natural number $n_1$ such that 
>   $$ S \leq s_{n_1} < S+1. \tag{1} $$
>
> Again as  $S = \inf \left\{ \ s_n \ \colon \ n \in \mathbb{N} \ \right\}$ and as $S-1 < S$, so $S - 1$ is also a lower bound for the set $\left\{ \ s_n \ \colon \ n \in \mathbb{N} \ \right\}$, and thus for every natural number $n$ we have 
>   $$ S-1 < S \leq s_{n},  $$
>   and hence 
>   $$ S-1 < s_{n}.  $$
>   In particular, for $n = n_1$, we can also write 
>   $$ S-1 < s_{n_1}. $$
>   And, as $s_{n_1} = \sup \left\{ \ x_k \ \colon \ k \in \mathbb{N}, k \geq n_1 \ \right\}$ and as $ S-1 < s_{n_1}$, so $S-1$ is not an upper bound for the set $\left\{ \ x_k \ \colon \ k \in \mathbb{N}, k \geq n_1 \ \right\}$ and thus there exists a natural number $k_1 \geq n_1$ such that 
>   $$ S-1 < x_{k_1} \leq s_{n_1}. \tag{2} $$
>
> From (1) and (2) we obtain 
>   $$ S-1 < x_{k_1} \leq s_{n_1} < S+1,  $$
>   and hence 
>   $$ S-1 < x_{k_1}  < S+1. \tag{3} $$
>
> Again as $S = \inf \left\{ \ s_n \ \colon \ n \in \mathbb{N} \ \right\}$ and as $S+1/2 > S$, so $S+1/2$ is not a lower bound for the set $\left\{ \ s_n \ \colon \ n \in \mathbb{N} \ \right\}$ and thus we can find a natural number $n_2$ such that 
>   $$ S \leq s_{n_2} < S+ \frac{1}{2}. \tag{4} $$
>
> Again as $S = \inf \left\{ \ s_n \ \colon \ n \in \mathbb{N} \ \right\}$ and as $S-1/2 < S$, so $S-1/2$ is also a lower bound for the set $\left\{ \ s_n \ \colon \ n \in \mathbb{N} \ \right\}$ and thus for every natural number $n$ we have 
>   $$ S - \frac{1}{2} < S \leq s_n, $$
>   which gives
>   $$ S - \frac{1}{2} < s_n. $$
>   In particular, for 
>   $$r_2 \colon= \max \left\{ \ n_2, k_1 + 1 \ \right\}, \tag{A} $$
>   we obtain 
>   $$ S- \frac{1}{2} < s_{r_2}.  $$
>
> Now as $s_{r_2} = \sup \left\{ \ x_k \ \colon \ k \in \mathbb{N}, k \geq r_2 \ \right\}$ and as $S-1/2 < s_{r_2}$, so $S - 1/2$ is not an upper bound for the set $\left\{ \ x_k \ \colon \ k \in \mathbb{N}, k \geq r_2 \ \right\}$ and thus  there exists a natural number $k_2 \geq r_2$ such that $$ S - \frac{1}{2} < x_{k_2} \leq s_{r_2}. \tag{5'} $$
>
> As $r_2 \geq n_2$ [Note (A) above.], so the set 
>   $\left\{ \ x_k \ \colon \ k \in \mathbb{N}, k \geq r_2 \ \right\} \subseteq \left\{ \ x_k \ \colon \ k \in \mathbb{N}, k \geq n_2 \ \right\}$ and so 
>   $$ s_{r_2} \leq s_{n_2}. \tag{5''} $$
>   From (5') and (5'') we obtain 
>   $$ S - \frac{1}{2} < x_{k_2} \leq s_{r_2} \leq s_{n_2}, $$
>   and hence 
>   $$ S-\frac{1}{2} < x_{k_2} \leq s_{n_2}. \tag{5} $$
>
> From (4) and (5) we obtain 
>   $$ S - \frac{1}{2} < x_{k_2} \leq s_{n_2} < S+ \frac{1}{2}, $$
>   and hence 
>   $$ S - \frac{1}{2} < x_{k_2} < S+ \frac{1}{2}. \tag{6}  $$
>
> Finally as $k_2 \geq r_2$ and from (A) as $r_2 \geq k_1 + 1$, so $k_2 > k_1$ also. Thus our desired process can continue.

Answer (score 3):

Denote $\limsup x_{n}=S$. There is an $n_{1}$ such that 
$$ S+1 > \sup_{k\geq n_{1}} x_{k} = s_{n_1}. $$
Since 
$$ S-1 < \inf_{n \in \mathbb{N} } \sup_{k \geq n} x_{k} \leq \sup_{k\geq n}x_{k}, $$ for each $n=1,2,...$, then 
$$ S-1 < \sup_{k\geq n_{1} } x_{k},$$
which implies then that there is an $k_{1} \geq n_{1}$ such that 
$$ S-1 < x_{k_{1}}.$$
We also have 
$$ x_{k_{1}} \leq \sup_{k\geq n_{1}}x_{k}<S+1. $$

There is an $n_{2}$ such that 
$$ S+1/2> \sup_{k\geq n_{2}} x_{k} .$$
Since 
$$ S-1/2 < \inf_{n \in \mathbb{N} } \sup_{k\geq n}x_{k} \leq \sup_{k\geq n}x_{k} $$ 
for each   $n=1,2,...$, which implies then that 
$$ S-1/2 < \sup_{k\geq\max\{ n_{2}, k_{1}+1\}} x_{k}.$$ 
Choose a $k_2$ such that 
$$ k_{2} \geq \max\{n_{2}, k_{1}+1\} $$ 
and such that 
$$ S-1/2 < x_{k_{2}}. $$ 
We also have 
$$ x_{k_{2}} \leq \sup_{k\geq n_{2}} x_{k} < S+1/2. $$

Proceed in this way.

Comment: Do you agree with my edits? I've only sought to use the symbols that are in my original post and to make the mathematics easier for me to follow.

Comment: Okay, no problem.

Answer (score 1):

$(s_n)$ is the sequence of $s_n \colon= \sup \left\{ \ x_k \ \colon \ k \geq n \ \right\}$. If you observe, this is a decreasing sequence, because the first term of this sequence will be the supremum of the entire set. The second term of the sequence will be the supremum of it's 1st tail and so on.

Now, since $(x_n)$ is bounded, this implies that $(s_n)$ is bounded and then we can apply the monotone convergence theorem and claim that the sequence converges to its infimum.

Since $(s_n)$ is a subsequence of $(x_n)$, and its limit is $ S \colon= \inf \left\{ s_n \right\}$, then you have your result.

Comment: no, I don't think that $\left( s_n \right)$ is always a subsequence of $\left( x_n \right)$.

Comment: have a look at my post now, especially the P.S.

Answer (score 0):

Hints: (1) Show that for every cluster point, there is a subsequence converging towards it.

(2) Show that $\limsup x_n$ is a cluster point.

Comment: can you please have a look at my post, esp. the PS?